# pcap - not receiving traffic [OS X, El Capitan]

Tags: c, macos, networking, pcap, libpcap

I am creating a software switch, as a school project. It's implemented in C using lpcap and working fine (despite some bugs) on my Ubuntu machine. However I have a Mac and it's not working there as it should.

When frame is captured using pcap_next_ex() number of captured frames is increased. For some reason during first few seconds (5 to 30) it doesn't increment number of frames, like no frames were received, BUT I CAN SEE those frames in Wireshark. How is this possible?

If interested here is my code.
https://github.com/Horkyze/Software-switch

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> For some reason during first few seconds (5 to 30) it doesn't increment number of frames, like no frames were received,

Or, rather, like no frames were passed from the capture mechanism to libpcap.

Given that you did not set a timeout, the default timeout is used.  It happens to be 0; the behavior with a timeout is platform-dependent and undefined and, for systems that use BPF, such as OS X (and *BSD and Solaris 11), that behavior is "don't pass packets from the capture mechanism to userland until there's no room for the next packet in the kernel packet buffer", which means that the delay between the reception of a frame and its delivery to userland could be arbitrarily long.

Apple's `pcap_set_timeout()` man page is more emphatic about this (and I'm going to change the standard libpcap man page to say the same thing:

```
   The behavior, if the timeout isn't specified, is undefined.  We  recom-
   mend always setting the timeout to a non-zero value.
```

Given the "switch" in the name of your application, you probably don't want any timeout at all but instead want "immediate mode".  In immediate mode, set with `pcap_set_immediate_mode()` rather than `pcap_set_timeout()`, packets are delivered to user mode as soon as they arrive.

This will also work on Ubuntu (including immediate mode if it's a new enough version of Ubuntu that it has a version of libpcap with immediate mode).  Note that, on a Linux system with a version of the kernel new enough to implement TPACKET_V3 and a version of libpcap new enough to use TPACKET_V3, the behavior can be quite different from versions of Linux where either the kernel or libpcap *doesn't* do TPACKET_V3, so setting the timeout is a good idea on *any* OS.

Comment: Thanks, I didnt know such function even exists, since there is no mention of it in pcap man. But now it works OK. I have one more question, I suspect that its true but just to clarify. Are injected packets with pcap_inject() recieved by pcap_next()?

Comment: "Thanks, I didnt know such function even exists, since there is no mention of it in pcap man." I'll add it to the main pcap man page; it has its own man page.

Comment: "OK. I have one more question, I suspect that its true but just to clarify. Are injected packets with pcap_inject() recieved by pcap_next()?"  Please ask that as a separate question; this is a Q&A site, not a forum, and the idea is that a question should be on its own, so that a user can find a question that's already been asked and answered (think of Q&A sites as crowdsourced FAQs).